# sprintf without memory allocation

Tags: c, printf

Is there a way to use `sprintf` without relying on memory allocation? I am working with an embedded system and do not want to introduce a heap. The following code in my application is requiring me to define `_sbrk`

```
char numBuffer[10];

sprintf(numBuffer, "%04x", value);
```

Comment: If `numBuffer` has automatic storage duration, you *don't* need allocated storage.

Comment: Nor do I want allocated storage. Yet it is still asking me to define _sbrk

Comment: `snprintf()` is your friend. (or `asprintf()` )

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question is sensible and the close reason makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sprintf is using heap internally. So your best bet is to write a version which doesn't. If you just use %d, %x and %s format specifiers, you won't need any dynamic memory.

Comment: Can you point to an implementation that would do such a thing?